# Distribution of Standard Brownian Motion squared

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

If the standard Brownian Motion $B_t$ has pdf

$$f(x)=(2\pi*t)^{-1/2}*\exp (-\frac{x^2}{2t})$$

how would one compute $B_t^2$?

I normally would show a lot of different things that I try myself before posting here, but I don't even know where to start, so if someone has any ideas, I would really appreciate the input!

[image]

Comment: This is not a Brownian motion, but a centered normal random variable. If you "do not even know where to start", you might want to share some cases where you know how to compute a distribution.

Comment: @Did according to my book it is, I modified the initial post

Comment: @darkblue The question could be reformulated in the following way: "Let $X \sim N(0,t)$. Compute the density of $X^2$." That's what Did meant: You don't need any properties of the Brownian motion, except $B_t \sim N(0,t)$.

Comment: Why not try "to share some cases where you know how to compute a distribution."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** Let $X$ be a random variable such that $X$ has a density and $\mathbb{P}(X=x) = 0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, the cumulative distribution function $F_{X^2}$ of $X^2$ equals $$\begin{align*} F_{X^2}(a) &:= \mathbb{P}(X^2 \leq a) = \mathbb{P}(-\sqrt{a} \leq X \leq \sqrt{a}) \\ &= \mathbb{P}(X \leq \sqrt{a})-\mathbb{P}(X<-\sqrt{a}) \\&= F_X(\sqrt{a})-F(-\sqrt{a}) \end{align*}$$ for any $a \geq 0$. Differentiate both sides in order to obtain the density $p_{X^2}$ of $X^2$.

Apply this to $X \sim N(0,t)$, i.e. a normal distributed random variable with mean $0$ and variance $t$.

**Remark** If $X \sim N(0,t)$, then $X^2$ is a [$\chi^2$-distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) random variable.

Comment: thank you for the hint! I can't believe I didn't see it!

Comment: @darkblue You are welcome. If you find the answer helpful, you might upvote/accept it by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: @saz Thanks for the answer. I used to solve the problem using this method in my undergraduate study. But in this question, the density of $B_t^2$ is only assume to be a positive measurable function,and it's integrable. So by lebesgue differentiation theorem, the integral can only be differentiated a.e. So can I know $p_{X^2}$ on $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @JohnZHANG The density is continuous. If you know the density for almost all $x$, then -because of continuity- you know it for all $x$.

Comment: @saz May I know why density of $B^2_t$ is continuous? I know density of $B_t$ is continuous since it's given. Does it imply the continuity of density of $B^2_t$? Or is it required by definition?

Comment: @JohnZHANG If follows from the continuity of the density of $B_t$. Recall that for any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with density $p$ and $q$, there is an explicit formula for the density of $X \cdot Y$ in terms of $p$ and $q$.

Comment: @saz Sorry, I still don't quite get it. May you kindly elaborate more on this problem in your original answer?

Comment: @JohnZHANG There is not much to elaborate. Do you know the formula I mentioned in my last comment? If not so, have you tried to find it?